# zip_longest for the left list always

Tags: python, iterator

I know about the `zip` function (which will zip according to the shortest list) and `zip_longest` (which will zip according to the longest list), but how would I zip according to the first list, regardless of whether it's the longest or not?

For example:

```
Input:  ['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2]
Output: [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', None)]
```

But also:

```
Input:  ['a', 'b'], [1, 2, 3]
Output: [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
```

Do both of these functionalities exist in one function?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

#### Solutions

Chaining the repeated fillvalue behind the iterables other than the first:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

def zip_first(first, *rest, fillvalue=None):
    return zip(first, *map(chain, rest, repeat(repeat(fillvalue))))
```

Or using `zip_longest` and trim it with a `compress` and `zip` trick:

```
def zip_first(first, *rest, fillvalue=None):
    a, b = tee(first)
    return compress(zip_longest(b, *rest, fillvalue=fillvalue), zip(a))
```

Just like `zip` and `zip_longest`, these take any number (well, at least one) of any kind of iterables (including infinite ones) and return an iterator (convert to list if needed).

#### Benchmark results

Benchmarks with other equally general solutions (all code is at the end of the answer):

```text
10 iterables of 10,000 to 90,000 elements, first has 50,000:
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 2.2 ms   2.2 ms   2.3 ms  limit_cheat
 2.6 ms   2.6 ms   2.6 ms  Kelly_Bundy_chain
 3.3 ms   3.3 ms   3.3 ms  Kelly_Bundy_compress
50.2 ms  50.6 ms  50.7 ms  CrazyChucky
54.7 ms  55.0 ms  55.0 ms  Sven_Marnach
74.8 ms  74.9 ms  75.0 ms  Mad_Physicist
 5.4 ms   5.4 ms   5.4 ms  Kelly_Bundy_3
 5.9 ms   6.0 ms   6.0 ms  Kelly_Bundy_4
 4.6 ms   4.7 ms   4.7 ms  Kelly_Bundy_5

10,000 iterables of 0 to 100 elements, first has 50:
────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 4.6 ms   4.7 ms   4.8 ms  limit_cheat
 4.8 ms   4.8 ms   4.8 ms  Kelly_Bundy_compress
 8.4 ms   8.4 ms   8.4 ms  Kelly_Bundy_chain
27.1 ms  27.3 ms  27.5 ms  CrazyChucky
38.3 ms  38.5 ms  38.7 ms  Sven_Marnach
73.0 ms  73.0 ms  73.1 ms  Mad_Physicist
 4.9 ms   4.9 ms   5.0 ms  Kelly_Bundy_3
 4.9 ms   4.9 ms   5.0 ms  Kelly_Bundy_4
 5.0 ms   5.0 ms   5.0 ms  Kelly_Bundy_5
```

The first one is a cheat that knows the length, included to show what's probably a limit for how fast we can get.

#### Explanations

A little explanation of the above two solutions:

The first solution, if used with for example three iterables, is equivalent to this:

```
def zip_first(first, second, third, fillvalue=None):
    filler = repeat(fillvalue)
    return zip(first,
               chain(second, filler),
               chain(third, filler))
```

The second solution basically lets `zip_longest` do the job. The only problem with that is that it doesn't stop when the first iterable is done. So I duplicate the first iterable (with `tee`) and then use one for its elements and the other for its length. The `zip(a)` wraps every element in a 1-tuple, and non-empty tuples are [true](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). So [`compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) gives me all tuples produced by `zip_longest`, as many as there are elements in the first iterable.

#### Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVZRi9s4EH7PrxCUEntxloTdhSOQQjftQbnrcrB9C8EoziRRK0s@WenG@fN7I8mW5TjZ5qhhN8mMZ@b7ZkYzKiq9k@Luj0K9vq5hQzjLmU6zHVAd3TANiq44lAnZMM5/Ur6H2ZMUEE8HBB8Feq8EYSVnGURHVqRcii2Ul0z9tzghNkTKQWz1Lh4MTOy/gPMqfdyLdYUIKBPRhqlSJ@RGgfl4CwMG92/ntIisfUKcoYLC8Kk/WhT4nIks8wLNymuC04SsyIxoAPd2HELyjsLErM44DNNieNAG1lzRYzXf7bMf1a@L8fz56duXp89/Ix65@g6Zjhwa@28jFWn4SL0DVRJmk/aLijVO6xjmYRvnCcvuY7balr8X1fFmZMGMMTOGQuoWMPAS2pgWKzPwnOHSO6oY8DWJujzqVD3/BJF@pUrQbHdd2yADAwlZRyq2QZUJahRLn7ODEVl30xMYB/QfCThgWwUhThzV4L7SdfrPripZxkymqdpeKuI7W5NVldqY0fDj4/zTMCHDQzUMLYajYUxGow/k44E8VmQ@Ip9Gl@yd@fHlTQfHQV1aUxiDr6UbVNO2iJZ1MU3mmHaMmTaUjaHL3cuOcSDf1B5aRzayNW1Lam2T2hzEPjcBIPKB4m5naVV1Bd4vurXFYPUZbB44ZFBgr2lZfLFOmRR9F7YtZzMy7qvONLS3alAu2BLj98bLRaT@lUFPW97SogCxjk5cuKbT@4KDU5VnRtfdb88sMzqRVr4Fbco7aSZSQq4fYueG6v01yEoQmgngpxPMNMnxdF51FsSiMV3Gb0LrTLHjYrw0s6ix7dZ@pYD@OEn/sU/s4Spi2H0FrJHXnxRnnZUZR0YeBaCEFFxmlDcGXtE6MEdqcKEvLcgrM@ZC/49s1RCuStKA5YVUmmiWA9ODjZK5PSxaSo6Lxyn9hjanptNfSX2jSEyTJn6POj@ycIeucdN2q9NnknNsHTzmPtIa/sWkDTZ7kdnxYwEHF53ECnq3jzPiGonTBNvZCcId5CSdwd/3d9cX3fdFD8lg6RpPmzKaIZtmmHhMApaoHvtzqRTSFiZPbu4V@BPZcrNyLHVsd7d7GuvIHFV/O8BX7LIzr4bTv9zzjp8LPsxTKCbMNcuZzGoQifV5m6aC5pCmwa3kHXkuoG5zXdraLJYWTeqhtLvYyhTFFokegt50QU9BhBhPQoeMscWam5BLkhH0tg4Cy/HouHa@rec8p/lqTaeuu85nJiFj/MOttgI1m8TdhaD9qD9ZWY7ATTR8f3872ZC8JEPynkSa3JAJ3Ll9a/dlic0NaF7Gi@mdmXwnebY9YyFt4CVd7bU9YKm/6DWjZ8vlCodOeCO38lCAKXgYp@Px2JXDXgD9yhsntTLu3K1qLe73idUiARa31ztXyonRxstwCYUTNSCRU1FZFuUOif8GjYsULsFnmP/JeHIeu@X9Bv720J6vQuwG02KCNTR3A/9jMZ2OJsvA/lIC4tfX/wA))

```
def limit_cheat(*iterables, fillvalue=None):
    return islice(zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=fillvalue), cheat_length)

def Kelly_Bundy_chain(first, *rest, fillvalue=None):
    return zip(first, *map(chain, rest, repeat(repeat(fillvalue))))

def Kelly_Bundy_compress(first, *rest, fillvalue=None):
    a, b = tee(first)
    return compress(zip_longest(b, *rest, fillvalue=fillvalue), zip(a))

def CrazyChucky(*iterables, fillvalue=None):
    SENTINEL = object()
    
    for first, *others in zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=SENTINEL):
        if first is SENTINEL:
            return
        others = [i if i is not SENTINEL else fillvalue for i in others]
        yield (first, *others)

def Sven_Marnach(first, *rest, fillvalue=None):
    rest = [iter(r) for r in rest]
    for x in first:
        yield x, *(next(r, fillvalue) for r in rest)

def Mad_Physicist(*args, fillvalue=None):
    # zip_by_first('ABCD', 'xy', fillvalue='-') --> Ax By C- D-
    # zip_by_first('ABC', 'xyzw', fillvalue='-') --> Ax By Cz
    if not args:
        return
    iterators = [iter(it) for it in args]
    while True:
        values = []
        for i, it in enumerate(iterators):
            try:
                value = next(it)
            except StopIteration:
                if i == 0:
                    return
                iterators[i] = repeat(fillvalue)
                value = fillvalue
            values.append(value)
        yield tuple(values)

def Kelly_Bundy_3(first, *rest, fillvalue=None):
    a, b = tee(first)
    return map(itemgetter(1), zip(a, zip_longest(b, *rest, fillvalue=fillvalue)))

def Kelly_Bundy_4(first, *rest, fillvalue=None):
    sentinel = object()
    for z in zip_longest(chain(first, [sentinel]), *rest, fillvalue=fillvalue):
        if z[0] is sentinel:
            break
        yield z

def Kelly_Bundy_5(first, *rest, fillvalue=None):
    stopped = False
    def stop():
        nonlocal stopped
        stopped = True
        return
        yield
    for z in zip_longest(chain(first, stop()), *rest, fillvalue=fillvalue):
        if stopped:
            break
        yield z


import timeit
from itertools import chain, repeat, zip_longest, islice, tee, compress
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import deque

funcs = [
    limit_cheat,
    Kelly_Bundy_chain,
    Kelly_Bundy_compress,
    CrazyChucky,
    Sven_Marnach,
    Mad_Physicist,
    Kelly_Bundy_3,
    Kelly_Bundy_4,
    Kelly_Bundy_5,
]

def test(args_creator):

    # Correctness
    expect = list(funcs[0](*args_creator()))
    for func in funcs:
        result = list(func(*args_creator()))
        print(result == expect, func.__name__)
    
    # Speed
    tss = [[] for _ in funcs]
    for _ in range(5):
        print()
        print(args_creator.__name__)
        for func, ts in zip(funcs, tss):
            t = min(timeit.repeat(lambda: deque(func(*args_creator()), 0), number=1))
            ts.append(t)
            print(*('%4.1f ms ' % (t * 1e3) for t in sorted(ts)[:3]), func.__name__)

def args_few_but_long_iterables():
    global cheat_length
    cheat_length = 50_000
    first = repeat(0, 50_000)
    rest = [repeat(i, 10_000 * i) for i in range(1, 10)]
    return first, *rest

def args_many_but_short_iterables():
    global cheat_length
    cheat_length = 50
    first = repeat(0, 50)
    rest = [repeat(i, i % 101) for i in range(1, 10_000)]
    return first, *rest

test(args_few_but_long_iterables)
funcs[1:3] = funcs[1:3][::-1]
test(args_many_but_short_iterables)
```

Comment: Very very neat. Not exceptionally performant I'd imagine, but neat

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't know about "exceptionally" performant, but I expect it to be quite performant. Probably faster than yours :-P. Make a suggestion for what iterables to use in a benchmark and I'll write one.

Comment: 100 randomly generated lists of strings with ~1000 elements each would be a good place to start. Benchmark using `list` or `deque(..., maxlen=0)`

Comment: I had completely forgotten about additional arguments to `map`, so it took me a good 2-3 minutes to realize what you were doing here :) My only suggestion is to add argument `fillvalue=None` and change `repeat(repeat(None))` to `repeat(repeat(fillvalue))`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ok I'll try that as well. Just finished a benchmark with `first = repeat(0, 50_000)` and `rest = [repeat(i, 10_000 * i) for i in range(1, 10)]`, where yours takes 75 ms and mine takes 2.7 ms :-D

Comment: That should be sufficient. Can you post the test code here?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Added.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Included another solution and a cheat now. Looks like at least for this test case, I'm quite close to the limit of what's possible. I also tried with 100 iterables (`first = repeat(0, 5_000)` and `rest = [repeat(i, 100 * i) for i in range(1, 100)]`), the results didn't change much.

Comment: I'm not at a computer to check right now, but I'm curious if a list comprehension ( `*[chain(it, repeat(fillvalue)) for it in rest]` ) would be any faster or slower than `map`. (I personally find it easier to visually grok, though I know mileage varies on this matter.)

Comment: @CrazyChucky In my benchmark with few but long iterables it doesn't make a difference, but in my other benchmark (just added) with many but short iterables it's slower: ~24.9 ms instead of ~18.6 ms. Generally `map` is faster than a list comprehension when both use a function. More importantly, you create one `repeat` for each iterable, while I create only a single shared one that gets chained onto all iterables. Your list comp with a single prepared one as well takes ~19.5 ms.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Hmm... when you said "Not exceptionally performant I'd imagine", did you think it is slow? If so, why? Btw it does slow down for a *large number* of *short* iterables (see the second benchmark), though my other solutions handle that well. Particularly my new one using `compress` and `tee` appears very good in all cases, and I love every time I can use those two rarely used itertools to my advantage :-)

Answer (score 11):

You can repurpose the "roughly equivalent" python code shown in the docs for [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to make a generalized version that zips according to the length of the first argument:

```
from itertools import repeat

def zip_by_first(*args, fillvalue=None):
    # zip_by_first('ABCD', 'xy', fillvalue='-') --> Ax By C- D-
    # zip_by_first('ABC', 'xyzw', fillvalue='-') --> Ax By Cz
    if not args:
        return
    iterators = [iter(it) for it in args]
    while True:
        values = []
        for i, it in enumerate(iterators):
            try:
                value = next(it)
            except StopIteration:
                if i == 0:
                    return
                iterators[i] = repeat(fillvalue)
                value = fillvalue
            values.append(value)
        yield tuple(values)
```

You might be able to make some small improvements like caching `repeat(fillvalue)` or so. The issue with this implementation is that it's written in Python, while most of `itertools` uses a much faster C implementation. You can see the effects of this by comparing against [Kelly Bundy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71520401/2988730).

Comment: It's much shorter if you just use `chain` eagerly for all the others ...

Comment: @o11c. Not sure I see how `chain` applies here

Comment: @o11c. I didn't use chain, but did shorten the code a bit

Comment: @MadPhysicist mostly `iterators = [chain(it, repeat(fillvalue)) for ...]` except don't do so for the first. Then you can remove the entire loop in favor of `yield from zip()`

Comment: @o11c Better `return` the `zip`, otherwise you'll pointlessly slow it down.

Comment: @o11c Tried it in my benchmark, using `yield from` slowed it down from 2.6 ms to 3.9 ms.

Answer (score 7):

Here's another take, if the goal is readable, easy to understand code:

```
def zip_first(first, *rest, fillvalue=None):
    rest = [iter(r) for r in rest]
    for x in first:
        yield x, *(next(r, fillvalue) for r in rest)
```

This uses the two-argument form of `next()` to return the fill value for all iterables that are exhausted.

For exactly two iterables, this can be simplified to

```
def zip_first(first, second, fillvalue=None):
    second = iter(second)
    for x in first:
        yield x, next(second, fillvalue)
```

Comment: Yep, this works too.

Comment: The version for two is what [Jan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71520269/12671057) should've been... at first sight it looks completely different, but it really just re-implemented `for` and two-arg `next`. Anyway, included your general version in my benchmark now.

Answer (score 5):

Make the second one infinite, and then just use normal zip:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2]

b = chain(b, repeat(None))

print(*zip(a, b))
```

Answer (score 1):

Return only `len(a)` elements from `zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def zip_first(a, b):
    z = zip_longest(a, b)
    for i, r in zip(range(len(a)), z):
        yield r
```

Comment: What if it's not a list?

Comment: The question states that it's a list, as does the example.

Comment: Probably yield items from both iterators until you hit `StopIteration` on the first argument.

Comment: OK. I made a fairly general solution that relies only on `StopIteration` from the first argument.

Comment: Instead of `for _, r in zip(range(len(a)), z): yield r` you can do `yield from islice(z, len(a))` where `islice` is imported from `itertools`.

Comment: @Stef Actually better `return` the islice then (as mkrieger's answer did). Wrapping it in a generator slows it down.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit ugly, but I would go with this one. The idea is to shorten the second list to the size of the first one if it is longer. Then we use `zip_longest` guaranteeing that the result is at least as long as the first argument of `zip`.

```
import itertools

input1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2]]
input2 = [['a', 'b'], [1, 2, 3]]

zip1 = itertools.zip_longest(input1[0], input1[1][:len(input1[0])])
zip2 = itertools.zip_longest(input2[0], input2[1][:len(input2[0])])

print(list(zip1))
print(list(zip2))
```

Output:

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', None)]
[('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
```

To zip multiple lists this can be used:

```
import itertools

def zip_first(lists):
    equal_lists = [l[:len(lists[0])] for l in lists]
    return itertools.zip_longest(*equal_lists)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of one readymade, but you can define your own.

Using `object()` as a sentinel ensures it will always test as unique, and never get confused with `None` or any other fill value. Thus this should behave properly even if either of your iterables contain `None`.

Like `zip_longest`, it takes any number of iterables (not necessarily two), and you can specify the `fillvalue`.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def zip_left(*iterables, fillvalue=None):
    SENTINEL = object()
    
    for first, *others in zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=SENTINEL):
        if first is SENTINEL:
            return
        others = [i if i is not SENTINEL else fillvalue for i in others]
        yield (first, *others)


print(list(zip_left(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2])))
print(list(zip_left(['a', 'b'], [1, 2, 3])))
```

Output:

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', None)]
[('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
```

Comment: What if there's a legitimate `None`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I did mention that...

Comment: You just said it wouldn't work...

Comment: @MadPhysicist P.S. I believe I've resolved that weakness.

Comment: Generate the sentinel within the function and I'll believe it too. Right now, it's publicly accessible and therefore error prone. Besides that, you have the right idea.

Comment: Also, you should check that `iterables` is not empty here (+1 regardless). The awkwardness of the solution is that now you have `zip_longest` and your function basically running the same check twice on each item.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful nudges. I'm unsure about that last one, though. What would you recommend the function do differently if `iterables` were empty? It already yields nothing, the same as `zip` or `zip_longest` do when supplied with no arguments. (And yes, your solution is a lot more elegant.)

Comment: Nevermind, you're right. But `yield first, *others` raises an error for me. Needs parens

Comment: Oh, interesting. Apparently this was a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272460/why-is-starred-iterable-unpacking-in-a-return-statement-invalid-syntax-without-p) from Python 3.2 through 3.7.

Comment: Interesting. I've always wondered about that, and it just stopped happening at some point. Now I'm on a machine with 3.6.9 again

Answer (score 1):

For generic iterators (or lists as well), you can use this. We yield pairs until we hit `StopIteration` on `a`. If we hit `StopIteration` on `b` first, we use `None` as the second value.

```
def zip_first(a, b):
    ai, bi = iter(a), iter(b)
    while True:
        try:
            aa = next(ai)
        except StopIteration:
            return           
        try:
            bb = next(bi)
        except StopIteration:
            bb = None
        yield aa, bb
```

Comment: Much shorter version of this: `for aa in a: yield aa, next(bi, None)`

Answer (score 1):

If the inputs are lists (or other collections which can be used with `len`), you can use `zip_longest` and lazily limit the result to the length of the first list<sup>1</sup>, by using `islice`:

```
from itertools import islice, zip_longest

def zip_first(a, b):
    return islice(zip_longest(a, b), len(a))
```

<sup>1</sup>This basic idea was taken from the [answer by Jan Christoph Terasa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71520109).

Answer (score 1):

idk but

```
first = ['a', 'b', 'c']
last = [1, 2, 3, 4]
if len(first) < len(last):
    b = list(zip(first, last))
else:
    b = list(zip_longest(first, last))
print(b)
```

Comment: What if there are more than two iterables? e.g. `zip(a, b, c)`?